# C# Email BCC displaying wrong recipient email address.

Tags: c#, .net

I'm having a strange problem with BCC. The recipients receiving the messages,
but in the To: field having the to email address.
So for example bcc1@server.com recipient getting the right message in the right mailbox but 
To: field instead of has to@server.com instead of bcc1@server.com. Same thing with the bcc2. Anybody can see a problem? What did I do wrong?

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@server.com", "Ben Miller");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("to@server.com", "Jane Clayton");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = "Test Subject.";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "Some body text";
MailAddress bcc1 = new MailAddress("bcc1@server.com", "BCC1 Reciever");
message.Bcc.Add(bcc1);
MailAddress bcc2 = new MailAddress("bcc2@server.com", "BCC2 Reciever");
message.Bcc.Add(bcc2);


SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new           System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@server.com", "pass");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
client.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: That's how BCC works.. the To field stays the same.

Comment: I guess I was wrong, was expecting that Bcc recipient would receive the message with his email address which assigned to Bcc.

Answer (score 2):

As per the Remarks from MSDN on MailMessage.Bcc property looks like its working correctly

> **Remarks on MSDN :** To add a BCC recipient to an e-mail message, create
>   a MailAddress for the recipient's address, and then add that object to
>   the collection returned by the Bcc property.
>
> ***When recipients view an e-mail message, the Bcc addresses are usually
>   not displayed.***

[MailMessage.Bcc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc.aspx)